# Qt: How to catch an error with system call?

Tags: c++, qt, qprocess, qtcore, qiodevice

I am building a GUI application where I do a system call and call for gnuplot to run a script. Now i want to build in an error message that says when something is wrong (e.g. gnuplot is not installed or in the wrong path).

So I've been thinking about just putting out a QMessageBox, but I don't know how I can check whether the system call succeeded or not.

```
if(//System call didn't work)
{
    QMessageBox msgBox;
    msgBox.setWindowTitle("Error");
    msgBox.setIcon(QMessageBox::Critical);
    msgBox.setText("GNUPLOT was not installed");
    msgBox.exec();
}
```

My system call looks like this:

```
system(gnuplot script.txt);
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should use [QProcess](http://doc-snapshot.qt-project.org/qdoc/qprocess.html) rather than low-level system call because it is a nice abstraction in a Qt codebase. Otherwise, you will end up dealing with platform specific bits. `QProcess` already solves that for you. If you happen to be fine with a blocking approach, aka. sync, you could write something like that code below.

```
QProcess process;

process1.start("gnuplot arg1 arg2 etc");

// Wait for it to start
if(!process.waitForStarted())
    return 0;

bool retval = false;
QByteArray buffer;
while ((retval = process.waitForFinished()));
    buffer.append(process.readAll());

if (!retval) {
    qDebug() << "Process 2 error:" << process.errorString();
    msgBox.setText(buffer);
    return 1;
}
```

If you would not like to block while the gnuplot script of yours is running, you could connect a slot, or simply lambda with C++11 and on, to the [readyRead()](http://doc-snapshot.qt-project.org/qdoc/qiodevice.html#readyRead) signal. For sure, you would also need to connect to the [error()](http://doc-snapshot.qt-project.org/qdoc/qprocess.html#error-2) signal. The code without lambda to work with pre C++11 environments would look something like this:

```
GnuPlotReader::GnuPlotReader(QQProcess *process, QObject *parent)
    : QObject(parent)
    , m_process(process)
    , m_standardOutput(stdout)
{
    connect(m_process, SIGNAL(readyRead()), SLOT(handleReadyRead()));
    connect(m_process, SIGNAL(error(QProcess::ProcessError)), SLOT(handleError(QProcess::ProcessError)));
    connect(&m_timer, SIGNAL(timeout()), SLOT(handleTimeout()));

    m_timer.start(5000);
}

GnuPlotReader::~GnuPlotReader()
{
}

void GnuPlotReader::handleReadyRead()
{
    m_readData = m_process->readAll();

    if (!m_timer.isActive())
        m_timer.start(5000);
}

void GnuPlotReader::handleTimeout()
{
    if (m_readData.isEmpty()) {
        m_standardOutput << QObject::tr("No data was currently available for reading from gnuplot") << endl;
    } else {
        m_standardOutput << QObject::tr("GnuPlot successfully run")<< endl;
    }

}

void GnuPlotReader::handleError(QProcess::ProcessError processError)
{
    if (processError == QProcess::ReadError) {
        m_standardOutput << QObject::tr("An I/O error occurred while reading the data, error: %2").arg(m_process->errorString()) << endl;
        messageBox.setText(m_readData);
    }
}
```

Comment: I also would recommend to deal with async API, rather than with functions like `waitForStarted` which blocks the event loop.

Comment: @fasked: both are valid use cases, henced mentioned both.

Comment: I have tried using QProcess without success, I am trying it again, but it doesn't seem to work that way. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20841116/ i explain the exact thing i want to do and what i've tried so far

Comment: That is because you are not specifying the full path to your _local_ gnuplot installation. Of course, if it is not in the PATH, you will need the correct relative or absolute path. It is no different to the shell operation. :)